# Python string range does not produce the last character

Tags: python

The word `Hello` contains 5 characters.

```
>>> x = 'Hello'
>>>
>>> len(x)
5
>>>
```

`x[5]` will produce an error as Python number is started from 0. I can understand this.

```
>>> x[5]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: string index out of range
>>> 

>>> x[0]
'H'
>>>
```

And last charactor is at `x[4]`

```
>>> x[4]
'o'
>>>
```

However, when I try a range which is from `x[0:4]`, the last letter is not there.

```
>>> x[0:4]
'Hell'
>>>
```

May I know why?

Comment: range's upper bound is **excluded**

Answer (score 1):

Slicing from 0 to 4 will produce items 0, 1, 2, and 3. If you want to include the las one use

```py
x[0:5]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x[0:4]
```

means

index `4` is excluded.

There is a rationale behind that. You can just substract the two numbers to calculate the length of outcome. :)

Comment: The rationale is that you can do `x` corresponds to `x[0:len(x)]` and not `len(x)-1`

Answer (score 1):

In slicing, first int is included while last is excluded

Answer (score 1):

I believe the reason is the way most of those operations are performed:

```
for(x=start;x<end;x++){
   output[x]=input[x]
}
```

(pardon my C).

Another reason is consistency between slice operator and `len`. It's believed that `a[0:len(a)]` should return `a`.

Comment: Thanks @George. Would it be possible to view the actual source code of this slicing technique in Python? If yes, please let me know how or where is the actual code.